# Return statement not forcing to jump out of function

Tags: python

I am writting a recursive function to print number of square root of first occurring number between a given range of numbers.For example, between a range of 80 - 90, 81 is the first number which has a perfect square root which is 9. Also 9 has a perfect squreroot which is 3. but 3 does not have a perfect equre root. So the count should be 2: 81 : 9 -> 3. count = 2

```
import math

def sqrtCount(num, countVal):
    count = countVal
    root = math.sqrt(num)
    if int(root + 0.5) ** 2 != num:
        return count
    else:
        count += 1
        sqrtCount(root, count)
        return count


min = int(input("Enter Minimum number: "))
max = int(input("Enter Maximum number: "))

for i in range(min, max + 1):
    val = sqrtCount
    if val(i, 0) > 0:
        print(val(i, 0))
        break
```

Comment: There is no question mark in your question.

Comment: Issue is, after hitting return statement in if condition, it is still calling sqrtCount() function in else condition, instead of jumping out of the function.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code is quite hard to read.

```
val = sqrtCount
```

does not serve a good purpose here. It looks to me that you wanted

```
for i in range(min, max + 1):
    val = sqrtCount(i, 0)
    if val > 0:
        print(val)
        break
```

Also,

```
count = countVal
```

seems not helpful. Removing it will simplify the method and help yourself understanding it. Finally it will be as simple as

```
def sqrtCount(num, countVal):
    root = math.sqrt(num)
    if int(root + 0.5) ** 2 != num:
        return countVal
    else:
        return sqrtCount(root, countVal +1)
```